# Determine if four integers contain two pairs

Tags: java

Write a program that reads four integers and prints "two pairs" if the input consists of two matching pairs (in some order) and "not two pairs"

So far I have written:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n;
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int number3;
    int number4;

    System.out.println("Enter up to four numbers: ");
    n = s.nextInt();
}
```

I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is a homework assignment? I'll give you a few clues to help you along.

You need to determine if you have two matching pairs. So what defines a "matching pair"? Presumably a pair of values, that is equal to another pair of values.

So first, you split your input in 2 pairs. Next, you determine if the pairs are equal.

However, the assignment also says "in any order", which I find a little confusing. Maybe your teacher wants it for two pairs that have been permutated.
In that case, you'll arbitrarily call the first input value the first part of the first pair, and look if there is another value that matches it.
What's left is to see if the remaining two values also match.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better and shorter way to do this.. I'm working on it..meanwhile

```
public class pairs {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter four numbers:  ");
      int a = n.nextInt();
      int b = n.nextInt();
      int c = n.nextInt();
      int d = n.nextInt();

        if((a==b && c == d)|| (a==c && b==d) || (c==b && a==d)) {

        System.out.println("i found pairs: "+a+b+c+d );

         }
        else{
             System.out.println("nope: "+a+b+c+d );
        }
      }
    }
```